# Launch agents not lauching at system startup

Tags: macos, startup, launchd

I have several plist files in the folder `~/Library/LaunchAgents`. They all have the same permissions but two of them ([dotjs](https://github.com/defunkt/dotjs) and [pow](http://pow.cx/)) are not launching at login, even if they have the key `RunAtLoad` set to `true`. Does anyone know why they are not loading?

(I'm using Lion 10.7.3.)

EDIT: 
I am able to launch the files manually with the command: `launchctl load -w cx.pow.powd.plist` for example.

Comment: Have you checked the Console logs (/Applications/Utilities/Console.app)? There maybe some error messages in there that will give you a clue.

Comment: They're not supposed to run at startup. They are supposed to run when you log in.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Unless I've misunderstood what you meant, isn't that exactly when user launch agents run - when the user logs in?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen yeah sorry, that's what I meant.

Comment: @binarybob No messages in the console. Also, i'm able to launch them manually with `launchctl load -w cx.pow.powd.plist`.